# Как можно снизить качество спрайта?

Tags: c++, sfml

Есть спрайт:

```
Image sprite;
sprite.loadFromFile("sprite.png");
Texture spriteT;
spriteT.loadFromImage(sprite);
Sprite s;
s.setTexture(spriteT);
```

Мне нужно снизить качество этого спрайта. Использую SFML. Можете подсказать, как?

Comment: может уменьшить размеры, а потом вернуть?

Comment: что значит "снизить качество"?

Comment: @user7860670 качесттво спрайта чтоб меньше компьютер напрягался